# Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android - onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, bitmap, android-activity, oncreate

I'm using a camera via Intent to snap a image and then save it to an imageview. The intent camera is in landscape mode and the activity that it returns to is in portrait mode. So the activity changes orientation and it reloads a new activty. I'm trying to save this image in that imageview. However while returning back the to activity page it disappears once the activity is in portrait mode. When I added the onSaveInstanceState method it crashes with the error:

```
  Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android
```

I have added the code below:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_page);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        Bitmap photo = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("savedImage");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }

  }
```

I have saved the image as follows

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle icicle){
      super.onSaveInstanceState(icicle);
      imageView.buildDrawingCache();
      Parcelable bm = imageView.getDrawingCache();
      icicle.putParcelable("savedImage",bm);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas error is because the bitmap isn't there any more after the orientation change. Also, that Parcelable you're setting in onSavedInstanceState() may not be there. Think of it this way: Views are logically "higher level" than intents and the called-back results.

You can save an image to the file system from the camera before you populate a view with it.

So, more housekeeping. This is what I do in several production / released apps ... and there might be a better way (?)

1. Define a file (path & name) ahead of time *before* firing the camera intent.
2. Fire camera, grab its bitmap image via the intent->data parm passed into onActivityResult()
3. Still in onActivityResult, plop the bitmap into the View AND
4. Then write it to the known file (and close it).

Note that between step 2 & 3, you could compress the bitmap to save space.

To deal with the reorientation, have a routine in onStart or onResume - which get fired after onCreate():

1. Try open that known file
2. if it fails or has no data:

   then use some default image (could be a RES jpg),

   else file and its image is good: 
       put the image from the file into the imageView
3. close the file.

This way, you've got *something* to put in there, no matter what happens. Most of the time, it works as expected :))  ( He says after nearly breaking 4 people's wrists flipping android phones at high speeds LOL )

BTW - this problem can be further compounded because the camera hardware differs across vendors. Some devices stay oriented the same way before, during, and after camera processing. Others, like some (or all ?) newer Samsungs, flip the camera orientation no matter what you do (unless you drop to the hardware - which is way way more complex).

Is the device you're having problems with a Samsung ?  - just be aware that they can cause more headaches.

Comment: Cameras are headaches, good to be able to help u avoid a few :))